# How to retrieve specific string from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list = ['   2021-03-11 value:\test/2021/result-01.','   2021-03-11 value:\test/2021/result-02.', '   2021-03-11 value:\test/2021/result-03.', '   2021-03-11 value:\test/2021/result-04.']
```

I want to retrieve a list that looks like:

```
list = ['result-01', 'result-02', 'result-03']
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: So if i'm correct you want a list of what's behind the last /  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`rsplit`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to split from the right and [**`rstrip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the extra `.` left.

```
ll = [i.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].rstrip('.') for i in ll]
```

Comment: @TechG don't use `list` as your variable name, its a python builtin.